# String[] no longer working in visual code studio

Tags: java, arrays, visual-studio-code

I updated Visual Studio Code, created a  new file and messed around with Java and something broke. Can someone please help me out?

```
import java.util.*;
public class test 
{

  public static void main(String[] args) {
   
    String[] test = ("1,2,3,4,5");

    for (String i : test) {
    System.out.print(test);
      {
  }

}
```

This is usually how I input my code for my stuff but today I got an error:

> "Cannot Resolve String[] to String"

This has never happened to me before and I do not know what to do. I would appreciate if you can help me.

Comment: The closing brace for the loop is facing the wrong direction. You also probably meant to surround every number by quotation marks.

Comment: String[] test = new String[]{"1", "3", "4", "5"}; this is the way to declare arrays. you forgot to put 2 closing braces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code you provided, I guess this is what you want

```java
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] test = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};

        for (String i : test) {
            System.out.print(i);
        }

    }

}
```